# How to add a select event on a single element in a textarea in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example if my textarea is "Hello world" how to put a select event on world only in jquery

Comment: You wouldn't.  A word is not an event.  You bind the EVENT and then inspect the value of the textarea for the word you're interesting in.  So, decide what event you need (keypress, blur or whatever suits your requirements) and then get the value of the textarea and inspect it for the key word.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery - find text in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32295000/jquery-find-text-in-textarea)